# How do I assign each IBAction (within second ViewController) to perform under a specific selection in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Disclaimer: new to this, and will describe the problem to the best of my ability.

[image: App Screenshot]

I am creating an app that consists of a TableView with weeks 1 thru 8. When the user makes a selection, the app segues into a ViewController that looks the same for each selection. However, the buttons within this second view controller should send the user to a URL that is specific to the week selected. Right now, the app is showing the same links for every week selected. I basically need each week to have a set of unique URLs respective to that week.

My code is attached, and I am also attempting to attach a photo diagram of what that app should be doing.

```
import UIKit

struct WeekInfo {
    let description: String
    let url: URL
}

class WeekTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var week = [
    WeekInfo(description: "Week 0:", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Week 1:", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Week 2:", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Week 3:", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Week 4: ", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Week 5:", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Week 6:", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Week 7:", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Week 8:", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Final Prep", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    WeekInfo(description: "Final Project", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!)

    ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
         self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }




    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return week.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedWeek = week[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier:"moveToWeekDetail", sender:selectedWeek)
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = week[indexPath.row].description
        return cell

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if let weekViewController = segue.destination as? WeekDetailViewController{
            // Pass the week's info onto the detail view controller
            if let selectedWeek = sender as? WeekInfo {
                weekViewController.title = selectedWeek.description
                weekViewController.week = selectedWeek
            }
        }
    }
```

Next view controller:

```
import UIKit

class WeekDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var week: WeekInfo!


    @IBOutlet weak var lessonCompleteBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button4: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        lessonCompleteBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        lessonCompleteBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 20

    }
    @IBAction func lessonBtnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        sender.setTitle("Complete!", for: [])
        if lessonCompleteBtn.backgroundColor == UIColor.gray{
            lessonCompleteBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 17/255, green: 107/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        else if lessonCompleteBtn.backgroundColor == UIColor(red: 17/255, green: 107/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0){
            sender.setTitle("Mark Complete", for: [])
            lessonCompleteBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Button1(_ sender: Any) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://resourelink1.com")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func Button2(_ sender: Any) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://resourcelink2.com")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func Button3(_ sender: Any) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://resourcelink3.com")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func Button4(_ sender: Any) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://resourcelink4.com")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Then make it an array like

```
struct WeekInfo {
  let description: String
  let urls: [URL]
}


var week = [
WeekInfo(description: "Week 0:", urls:[ URL(string: "https://somewhere1.com")!, URL(string: "https://somewhere2.com")!]),
.......]
```

And in the second vc use it like `week.urls[0]` // set index as you need

Comment: I'm starting to see how this is making more sense. I understand I have to use weeks.urls[index] in the second VC but how would I implement that within the @IBAction? Thanks again!